# Idiom for expecting the same object in two different mock calls

Tags: java, easymock

Let's say I have the following code

```
Capture<A> a1 = new Capture<A>();
Capture<A> a2 = new Capture<A>();

expect(mock.call1(capture(a1)).andReturn(...);
expect(mock.call2(capture(a2)).andReturn(...);

replayAll();

//Stuff to be tested

verifyAll();

assertEquals(a1.getValue(), a2.getValue());
```

I don't really care about the contents of the captures beyond them being equal. What I would like to do is

```
expect(mock.call2(eq(a1.getValue())))
```

but that won't work, since, at setup time, `a1` obviously doesn't have a captured value, yet.

Is there any matcher or other mechanism I can apply that would allow me to set up the expectation at the appropriate time? Creating the two captures and asserting on them feels like an awful lot of overkill for this particular scenario...